# How to migrate Kafka from old Zookeeper cluster to new Zookeeper cluster with different znode parent path

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

I have a three-node Kafka cluster in service running on a separate three-node Zookeeper cluster. I intend to switch Kafka to use a new five-node Zookeeper cluster, and although I have found information about doing that, I have an extra wrinkle where Kafka will be using a custom znode parent path on the new cluster.

For instance, my current Kafka Zookeeper string looks something like this:

`192.0.2.11:2181,192.0.2.12:2181,192.0.2.13:2181`

I'm looking to switch it to this:

`192.0.2.21:2181,192.0.2.22:2181,192.0.2.23:2181,192.0.2.24:2181,192.0.2.25:2181/kafka/uid1`

The reason for this is that we intend to reuse the larger Zookeeper cluster for other Kafka clusters.  Don't worry, this is for testing and not production.  However, we still want to do this without losing any data on the stream that is coming into Kafka, so we want to do this without taking anything down.

Is this possible?

I have come across the following questions:

- [Copy/Migrate old zookeeper znode/data to new zookeeper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31861659/copy-migrate-old-zookeeper-znode-data-to-new-zookeeper)
- [best way to copy data across 2 zookeeper cluster?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29617733/best-way-to-copy-data-across-2-zookeeper-cluster)

Unfortunately they appear to require some downtime, which I'm hoping to avoid.

This page (https://qgraph.io/blog/migrating-kafka-zookeeper-cluster/) was a little more helpful in the way of rollover, but not with znode migration.

I've been looking for '*znode symlinks*' or '*specifying znode path per zookeeper server*' but neither seem possible.  Am I out of luck and require downtime and possibly lost data?

Comment: Hi @Duff did you find any way to do this? now that minimal data is kept in zookeeper  compared to previous versions of kafka, has it changed things in any way? If we talk about ```data loss``` what sort of data would be lost? considering consumer offsets are kept in kafka only now.

Comment: Hi @bestwishes, unfortunately I hadn't found a solution. We ended up having downtime. This was five years ago though, so there is potential that there is a solution out there now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By what I can tell, there is no way to move Kafka's parent znode without restarting Kafka.  There are no such things as hard or soft links for znodes:  https://www.igvita.com/2010/04/30/distributed-coordination-with-zookeeper/