# Consolidating multiple zookeeper for different kafka clusters

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

we have 5 kafka clusters with 5 diff zk clusters (1-1 relationship). we want to move to single zk cluster (because we end up wasting/investing too many machines just to make sure high availability of zk, 25 machines in our case). The zkpath for all the kafka cluster are diff (otherwise there might have been [some problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41858320/how-to-migrate-kafka-from-old-zookeeper-cluster-to-new-zookeeper-cluster-with-di)). as par [this](https://engineeringblog.yelp.com/2019/01/migrating-kafkas-zookeeper-with-no-downtime.html) and [this](https://medium.com/airbnb-engineering/migrating-kafka-transparently-between-zookeeper-clusters-e68a75062f65) resources it should be possible, but trying to understand if someone has tried it? We don't want any kafka downtime during the switchover. Putting kafka aside if we try to merge two zk cluster what would happen? Will it just merge disjoint keys?

Answer (score 0):

As long as you use unique chroots within the same cluster, you shouldn't experience any issues.

Note: as of Kafka 3.3.x, where kraft mode is announced as production ready, you don't even need Zookeeper.